# java script or angularjs condition check on object with "!" vs "!!"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, null-check

Can anyone explain, the difference between

> `<div ng-show="!user.name">` and `<div ng-show="!!user.name">`

I was wondering what

> !!

does? in angularjs
I googled it but didn't get relivent answer

Comment: It is a double negative. `true` evals to `true`; `!true` evals to `false`, `!!true` evals to `true`; `!!!true` evals to `false`; ....and you can keep going if you want. The main use is to take a truthy value and make it return a boolean true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a double [logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

- `true` evals to `true`
- `!true` evals to `false`
- `!!true` evals to `true`
- `!!!true` evals to `false`

  ....and you can keep going if you want.

The main use of `!!` generally is to take a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and have it result in a boolean `true` or `false`.

---

> [logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `!`
> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true

---

See also [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1260204)